# Slick2D GUI Button listener

Tags: button, user-interface, slick2d

I'm trying to make button in slick by extending AbstractComponent:

public class StandardButton extends AbstractComponent {

```
protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int Width;
protected int Height;
protected String Text;

public StandardButton(GUIContext container,int x, int y, String Text, int Width, int Height,ComponentListener listener) {
    super(container);
    this.Text=Text;
    setLocation(x, y);
    this.Width=Width;
    this.Height=Height;
    addListener(listener);



}

@Override 
public void render(GUIContext container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setLineWidth(2f);
    g.drawRect(x, y, Width, Height);
    g.drawString(Text, x+5, y+(Height/2-4));

}
 [...]
```

And in my state:

public class UpdaterState extends BasicGameState implements ComponentListener {
     private StandardButton buttonPlay;

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer container, final StateBasedGame game)
        throws SlickException {
        buttonPlay=new StandardButton(container,100,100,"Graj",60,30,new ComponentListener(){

            @Override
            public void componentActivated(AbstractComponent source) {
                State.nextState(0, game);

            }

        });
```

But nothing happens. My nestState method does not run when i click my button. How schould I do that correctly? I just want my program to do block in componentActivated method. Is that possible or i just need to chceck if mouse is released on my button field in update method all the time for all buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a quick peak at buckys videos which give you helpful tips on making stuff with slick 2d.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXNDBQfCd08&feature=share&list=PL22EF3E3752768216

That's a link to the playlist of his tutorials. One of the videos talks about making buttons and switching states. Good luck and I hope you make an amazing program :)