# How is the abstract component class used in slick 2d?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm somewhat new to slick 2d and in my project I was playing around with things like buttons. I would draw an image and listen for a click at the coordinates and it ended up being like 50 lines long which seemed pretty unnecessary.

But then I saw this thread [Slick 2d Button Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970481/slick2d-gui-button-listener); sadly it was dead so didn't help. What the guy was working on seemed really efficient but i have so far been unable to find any information on how to use it. If anyone can explain to me or show me how to use it that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a button like this in Slick 2D

```
protected Shape hitbox;    
private boolean inside = false;    

public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) {
     .
     .//drawing the picture of the button 
     .
    if(inside && container.getInput().isMousePressed(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)){
         //someone clicked the button
    }
}
public void init(GameContainer container) {
    //setting a hitbox up to recognize when the mouse is over the picture/button
    hitbox = new Rectangle(/*dimensions of your picture*/);
}


public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) {
    //this code finds out if the mouse is over the button
    int mouseX = container.getInput().getMouseX();
    int mouseY = container.getInput().getMouseY();
    inside = hitbox.contains(mouseX, mouseY))
}
```

Comment: yes this will work but what i am trying to do is create a new component so i can just initialise it inside the init method with a few parameters and render it at the render method. I've almost got it working though.

Comment: You can create a private array. 
On the initialization you create your Components and add them to the array.
In the render method you iterate over every component from your array and call the render function of these components.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found out how i could do this, in the button class I wrote :

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Shape;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.AbstractComponent;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.GUIContext;

public class Button extends AbstractComponent{

protected int width;
protected int height;
protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int mouseX;
protected int mouseY;
protected boolean pressed;
protected Shape hitbox;
protected boolean over;
protected String text;

public Button(GUIContext container, int x, int y, int width, int height, String text) {
    super(container);
    setLocation(x, y);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.text = text;
    hitbox = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

@Override
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

@Override
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public boolean isPressed() {
    return pressed;
}
public void update(GUIContext container) {
    mouseX = container.getInput().getMouseX();
    mouseY = container.getInput().getMouseY();
    over = hitbox.contains(mouseX, mouseY);

    if (over && container.getInput().isMousePressed(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)) {
        pressed = true;
    }else{
        pressed = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void render(GUIContext container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(text, x + width/2, y + height/2);
}
@Override
public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

and to use it in my frame i simply write:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState{
    public static final int ID = 1;
    private StateBasedGame game;
    private Button button;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException {
    this.game = game;
    button = new Button(container, 1280/2, 720/2, 200, 200, "Works");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    button.render(container, g);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) {
    button.update(container);
    if (button.isPressed()) {
        System.out.println("Works");
    }
}
```

}